# Media not found when using language prefixes (i18n_patterns)

Tags: django, internationalization

My images in my website work perfectly when I don't use the language prefix.

http://example.com/ displays my images correctly but http://example.com/en/ doesn't display my media because the urls for my media automatically become 'en/media/image.jpg' instead of 'media/image.jpg' where the media actually lives.

Is there a way tell django to not append the language prefix to my media urls?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

It wasn't django adding the prefix, it was the url() function in the css the one copying the prefix beacuse of the way it reads the relative paths.

This css was causing the problem in my template:

```
.thumb {
    background-image: url({{my_image_url}});
}
```

The my_image_url value was "media/image.jpg"
But the css url function interpreted as: "http://example.com/en/media/image.jpg"

So I changed the css to

```
.thumb {
    background-image: url(../{{my_image_url}});
}
```

This way the css url function looks for "http://example.com/media/image.jpg" without the language prefix.

I still don't know why I have to use the "../" in my url() so if you know the reason let me know but this fixed the problem and now my images are displayed correctly from pages with and without the language prefix.